# How to do Regexp/pattern-searching in gunzipped files?

Tags: debian, regular-expression, gzip

How to use regexp/pattern-searching under gunzipped files. For instance ummm... let's use -

```
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-4.8.0-1-amd64$ zcat changelog.gz | less
```

Now the way I use is when reading the contents via less, use the / to locate the name or whatever term I use but this doesn't work/scale well if name/term is repeated many a time.

I also tried -

```
 /usr/share/doc/linux-image-4.8.0-1-amd64$ zcat changelog.gz | grep $search-term | less
```

I do get the names/search-term but without the surrounding context as of date and other things.

Is there a way to get the search-term highlighted even if it duplicated n number of times while reading the changelog.gz

An example of what I mean https://gist.github.com/shirishag75/e1238c16d2d372c4cfc3f62e25da335a

As can be seen I do get the search term/regexp but without date-time context it is and can be somewhat meaningless without knowing when the changes happened.

Comment: Is it really relevant that the file is gziped for your question? You can use `zgrep` instead of `zcat | grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zgrep`:

```
zgrep 'PATTERN' file.gz
```

Then you may pipe that on to a pager such as `less` if you wish.

On GNU systems (Linux), `zgrep` will behave just like GNU `grep` with regards to colouring etc.

To get context around each match use something like `-C 5` (five lines of context).

---

`less` also does highlighting of matches (by default, unless turned off with `-G`):

```
zless -p 'PATTERN' file.gz
```

This will open the decompressed file in `less` and search for `PATTERN`. Use <kbd>n</kbd> to skip to the next match in the file, or <kbd>N</kbd> to go back to the previous match.

Comment: I still get the search -terms but again without date/time context. Editing the question to have more clarity.

Comment: @shirish I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To uncompress and see the matches in colour, in context, make use of the grep -C and --color arguments.  Example below.

```
gzip -dc changelog.gz | grep -C 5 --color $search-term
```